# Can `Layout::from_value(&v)` and `Layout::new::<T>` can ever be different where `v : T` in Rust?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I'm implementing my own `Box<T>` from standard library to learn how to write unsafe code.

My implementation looks something like:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::{alloc, mem, ptr};
use ptr::NonNull;
use alloc::Layout;

pub struct MyBox<T> {
    data: NonNull<T>,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> MyBox<T> {
        unsafe {
            let layout = Layout::for_value(&data);
            let ptr = alloc::alloc(layout) as *mut T;
            ptr::write(ptr, data);
            let ptr = NonNull::new(ptr).unwrap_or_else(|| alloc::handle_alloc_error(layout));
            MyBox {
                data: ptr,
                _marker: PhantomData,
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for MyBox<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let ptr = self.data.as_ptr();
            drop(ptr::read(ptr));
            alloc::dealloc(ptr as *mut u8, Layout::new::<T>())
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use different methods to obtain the layout, however, `dealloc` requires us to use the same layout which was used to allocate the value.

According to the source code of those methods, `Layout::for_value` uses `mem::size_of_val` and `mem::align_of_val` while `Layout::new` uses `mem::size_of` and `mem::align_of`. As far as I could grasp from the documentation, they can only be different if T is a dynamically-sized type (DST). So as far as I implement `MyBox` for sized types only (and they actually are unless explicitly specified) I should be fine, shouldn't I?

Comment: nit: `drop(ptr::read(ptr))` should  probably be `ptr.drop_in_place()`

Comment: @PitaJ Didn't know about this function. Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, `Layout::from_value` and `Layout::new` only differ when you refer to dynamically sized types. (See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html for some examples of why the `of_value`/`from_value` versions exist) However, this will not make a difference in your case as `MyBox` only accepts sized types at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `std::mem::size_of_val`:

> This is usually the same as `size_of::<T>()`. However, when `T` *has* no
> statically-known size, e.g., a slice [`[T]`][slice] or a [trait object],
> then `size_of_val` can be used to get the dynamically-known size.

By default, when you introduce a type parameter, `T`, as you've done in `MyBox<T>`, there is an implicit `T: Sized` constraint. This means that both `mem::size_of_val` and `mem::size_of` will return the same thing.

In order to support unsized `T`, you need to make that explicit:

```
pub struct MyBox<T> where T: ?Sized {
  // ...
}
```

And:

```
impl<T> Drop for MyBox<T> where T: ?Sized {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that your `new` function still needs to have `T: Sized` because it needs to accept it as an argument by value. You may however find other ways to construct a `MyBox` for DSTs.

With this change, you now can't use `Layout::new<T>()`, because it requires `T: Sized`. Instead, you'll need to construct the `Layout` using `for_value`, which doesn't have the `Sized` constraint.

```
pub struct MyBox<T: ?Sized> {
    data: NonNull<T>,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Drop for MyBox<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let ptr = self.data.as_ptr();
            let layout = Layout::for_value(unsafe { &*ptr } );
            ptr.drop_in_place();
            alloc::dealloc(ptr as *mut u8, layout)
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to change `drop(ptr::read(ptr));` to `ptr.drop_in_place()` - partly because it's better, but *mostly* because `drop` requires `T: Sized` too :)